# access nodejs hosted in docker container in another container using web application

Tags: node.js, docker

I have 3 containers running:

1. nodejs
2. tomcat
3. mysql

tomcat container is able to connect to mysql .
node is able to connect to mysql.

However when tomcat container tries to connect to node on a http request using **node-container-id:3004/3333** as **hostname:port** OR **node-container-internal-ip:3004/3333** as **hostip:port**, it keeps giving 404 error.

My docker-compose.yml is as follows:

```
version: '2.1'

services:

  openmrs-referenceapplication-mysql:
    restart: "always"
    image: mysql:5.7
    ports:
      - 3333:3306
    command: "mysqld --character-set-server=utf8 --collation-server=utf8_general_ci"
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ${MYSQL_DB:-openmrs}
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD:-root-pass}
      MYSQL_USER: ${MYSQL_USER:-openmrs_user}
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD:-my-pass}
    healthcheck:
      test: "exit 0"
    volumes:
      - openmrs-referenceapplication-mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql

  openmrs-referenceapplication-node:
    restart: "always"
    image: node:12.20.1
    depends_on :
      - openmrs-referenceapplication-mysql
    expose:
      - "3004"
    ports:
      - "3009:3004"
    links:
      - openmrs-referenceapplication-mysql
      - openmrs-referenceapplication
    environment:
      DB_DATABASE: ${MYSQL_DB:-my-db}
      DB_HOST: openmrs-referenceapplication-mysql
      DB_USERNAME: ${MYSQL_USER:-root}
      DB_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD:-my-pass}
    volumes:
     - openmrs-referenceapplication-node-data:/home/azureuser/my-dir
     - ./Mydir:/Mydir
    command: node ./Mydir/bin/www


  openmrs-referenceapplication:
    restart: "always"
    image: openmrs/openmrs-reference-application-distro:2.8.0
    depends_on:
      - openmrs-referenceapplication-mysql
    ports:
      - "8001:8080"
    links:
      - openmrs-referenceapplication-mysql
    environment:
      DB_DATABASE: ${MYSQL_DB:-openmrs}
      DB_HOST: openmrs-referenceapplication-mysql
      DB_USERNAME: ${MYSQL_USER:-openmrs_user}
      DB_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD:-my-pass}
      DB_CREATE_TABLES: 'true'
      DB_AUTO_UPDATE: 'true'
      MODULE_WEB_ADMIN: 'true'
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://localhost:8080/openmrs/"]
      timeout: 20s
    volumes:
      - openmrs-referenceapplication-data:/usr/local/tomcat/.OpenMRS/
      - /usr/local/tomcat/.OpenMRS/modules/ # do not store modules in data
      - /usr/local/tomcat/.OpenMRS/owa/ # do not store owa in data
      - ./webservices.rest-2.29.0.omod://usr/local/tomcat/.OpenMRS/modules/webservices.rest-2.29.0.omod
      - /var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/ROOT.war:/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT
     
volumes:
   openmrs-referenceapplication-mysql-data:
   openmrs-referenceapplication-data:
   openmrs-referenceapplication-node-data:
```

Any idea what am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: If you're getting an HTTP 404 ("not found") error, that usually implies you're successfully connecting to your destination but the HTTP path part is wrong; the `http://openmrs-referenceapplication-node:3004` part of the URL is right and the Docker wiring is functional.  Can you include an actual URL you're trying to unsuccessfully call and the error you're getting?  Is any part of this a link that's getting resolved in the browser instead of a cross-container call?

Comment: @DavidMaze, when I run this sudo docker exec -it a442dfd21669 curl -k 'https://172.18.0.4:3004/api/mindmap'   - it gives me correct response , but if I call same URL from browser it returns a gateway timeout error

Comment: True, you can't use the container-private IP addresses from outside Docker usually (and don't need them inside Docker either; it is generally unnecessary to look them up at all).  You need to use the host's IP address or DNS name and the first port number from `ports:`, maybe `http://localhost:3009/api/mindmap` if the browser and containers are on the same system.

Comment: @David can you post this as an answer. Need to accept :). Can not thank you enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ey !

Your container can be reached with the service name (and only this). So if you want to reach your node container from another one you have to enter this adress: `http://openmrs-referenceapplication-node/<sub_path>`. To reach your service outside your container (on your local machine), you just have to go to :`localhost:3009`, in your case.

The best way to tackle conectivity issues is to enter the container and try to ping the container you target. Moreover you should use a more recent version of compose with `networks` instead of `links`.

Comment: when I run this sudo docker exec -it a442dfd21669 curl -k '172.18.0.4:3004/api/mindmap' - it gives me correct response , but if I call same URL from browser it returns a gateway timeout error

Comment: My bad, I thought you wanted to reach it from another container. When you are outside a container (on your local machine), you can reach your service on `localhost:<outside_port>`, outisde port which is 3009 in your case.